# How to extract a specific value(only value without its key) in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I used python to write a dictionary of a customer:

```
customer = {'name': name, 'phone_number': phone_number, 'code': code1}
```

the key-values of this dictionary have been defined.My trouble is :
When I want to check the value of the `input_name` (the user inputs) whether is the same as the value of the key `name` (in dictionary), I don't know how to extract the value of the key `name`  in dictionary. Should I use the method `.value` of a dictionary?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Just use `customer["name"]` or `customer.get('name', 'some_default_value_if_it_does_not_exist')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if input_name == customer['name']:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following

```
customer['name'] == input_name
```

Or if you don't know if the 'name' is actually in the dictionary

```
customer.get('name', 'default_value') == input_name
```

Both of the above statements will evaluate to `True` if the `input_name` is the same as the name in dictionary, `False` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
print("Yes" if input_name == customer['name'] else "No")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get method.

```
 value = customer.get('name',  None)
```

If the name doesn't exist, it will return None